# Having trouble with Firebase Database data retrival

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to create a login function. For a project. It works and all but the reading the data happens after it is checked so it login in no matter if the account can be found. I 've tried many things and some of it has stopped the login but I believe it is just this problem of not reading in time. But then it does have problems on other sample code I have made. I know this is a simple question and probably really obvious but if someone could lend some of their knowledge that would be really helpful, spent days stumped on this.
Submit btn presses calls

```
function login_4() {
    logIt_3(L, 'login_4', 'submit button pressed');
    if (document.getElementById("inputPName0").value !== "" && document.getElementById("inputPName1").value !== "") {
        //Give this session player names
        pName0 = document.getElementById("inputPName0").value;
        pName1 = document.getElementById("inputPName1").value;
        //DB stuff
        name = newAccount_4('One', "0", pName0);
        logIt_3(L, 'login_4', name);
        if (name == false) {
            return false
        }   
        name = newAccount_4('Two', "1", pName1);
        logIt_3(L, 'login_4', name);
        if (name == false ) {
            return false
        }

        //Populate
        document.getElementById("pName0").innerHTML = pName0;
        document.getElementById("pName1").innerHTML = pName1;
        
        
        //Change screen
        document.getElementById("landingPage").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("gamePage").style.display = "block";
        logIt_3(L, 'login_4', 'logged in');
        return
    }
    //error message
    logIt_3(E, "login_4", "cant login without two player names");
    document.getElementById("loginErrMsg").innerHTML = "Please enter a Names for BOTH!";
    return
}
```

Which in turn calls

```
function newAccount_4(_player, _playerNum, _pName) {
    name = dbRead_1("users", _pName);
    logIt_3(L, 'newAccount_4', name);
    if (name == false) {
        logIt_3(I, "newAccount_4", "ready to make new account.")
        document.getElementById("loginErrMsg" + _playerNum).innerHTML = "Please enter in new name for player " + _player;
        document.getElementById(("newAcc" + _playerNum)).style.display = "inline";
        return false
    }
    logIt_3(I, "newAccount_4", "Found name: " + _pName);
    return true
}
```

And now it shows this in the console. I will add below my DB code just so can see it reading. Also add the console logs so you can see the order.

```
function dbRead_1(_path, _key) {
    logIt_3(L, "dbRead_1", "reading database for: " + _key);
    readStatus = "waiting...";
  
    dbRef = database.ref(_path + '/' + _key).once("value", function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() != null) {
            var childData = snapshot.val();
            dbRec = {
                name: childData.name,
                score: childData.score
            };
            highScore = childData.score;
            logIt_3(L, "dbRead_1", "read " + dbRec);
            document.getElementById("dbReadStatus").innerHTML = "ok";
            return true;
        
        } 
        else {
            logIt_3(L, "dbRead_1", "couldnt find record");
            document.getElementById("dbReadStatus").innerHTML = "no record";
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I know the console logs arent the best but they have enough infomation to make sense atleast. I have copied and pasted them below

> login_4: submit button pressed
>
> 3logging.js:44 dbRead_1: reading database for: testpass
>
> 3logging.js:44 newAccount_4: undefined
>
> 3logging.js:38 newAccount_4: Found name: testpass
>
> 3logging.js:44 login_4: true
>
> 3logging.js:44 dbRead_1: reading database for: testfail
>
> 3logging.js:44 newAccount_4: undefined
>
> 3logging.js:38 newAccount_4: Found name: testfail
>
> 3logging.js:44 login_4: true
>
> 3logging.js:44 login_4: logged in
>
> 3logging.js:44 dbRead_1: read [object Object]
>
> 3logging.js:44 dbRead_1: couldnt find record

Comment: The `dbRead_1` function isn't returning anything. Try adding `return dbRef = database...`

Comment: It isn't supposed to return anything but either a true or false because it is only checking for a specific result, so it is either there or isnt.

Comment: It also more the fact that if you can see the console log that it isn't coming back in time fast enough so it automatically assuming it found the name